# Using cursor to retrieve one row of data (all entries from one id)

Tags: android

I'm starting my first trip into sqlite databases in an Android app, so far I can add to a database, I can update an entry in a database and I can display every bit of data in a database, but what I'm stuck with is how to get one entry (well one id and all its associated rows).

To retrieve all the rows I use this code

Database helper:

```
public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+table_name,null);
    return res;
}
```

and to call it in my activity class

```
public void viewallFunction() {
        Cursor res = characterDB.getAllData();

        if(res.getCount() == 0) {
            showmessage("Error","no Data");
            return;
        } else {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            while (res.moveToNext()) {
                buffer.append("Internal ID : " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Player Name : " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Character Name : " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                buffer.append("NickName : " + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Alignment : " + res.getString(4) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Race : " + res.getString(5) + "\n");
            }

            showmessage("Data", buffer.toString());
        }
    }
```

when called this works great (there's actually 81 entries so res.getString(0) all the way to res.getString(80) the functions trimmed for this post)

From what I understand the `*` in:

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + table_name, null);
```

means all columns.

So I created this method in my database helper :

```
public Cursor getOneData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select "+id+" from "+table_name,null);
    return res;
}
```

and called it with

```
public void getOneId(int id) {
    Cursor res = characterDB.getOneData(id);

    if(res.getCount() == 0){showmessage("Error","no Data");
        return;}
    else{
        showmessage("test","retreived id "+res.getString(0)+" which is "+res.getString(1));
        displaySheet(res.getString(0),
                res.getString(1),
                res.getString(2),
                res.getString(3),
                res.getString(4),
                res.getString(5),
        );}
}
```

Again that's trimmed for this post, display sheet then deals with the data, however nothing happens, i do not get either of the messages (which I'm sure is an impossibility, one or the other should display!) I do not get any errors either, just nothing happens, at first i thought the method was not even firing but I rewrote it to:

```
public void getOneId(int id){
    showmessage("Message","id is "+id);
}
```

and the test message showed perfectly

It has me completely stumped, a few hours of googling has got me more confused, each example i see is tailored very specifically to the app being made and looks nothing remotely like my code, which if the all display method didn't work I would say ah ha there's my problem, but my all display method does work...and well that's how I have learned it over the last 3 or 4 days (oh god please tell me I'm not doing it wrong)

So yeah what am I doing wrong?

How am I meant to retrieve one row as a set of strings?

For reference the first column in the table is set as

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

not sure if that's relevant or not though

**EDIT**: the database is structured like so:

```
1 "david" "zarr" "the great" "choatic" "human"
2 "george" "tod" "toddy" "lawful" "elf"
```

ie:

```
int string string string string string
```

The column names being :

```
ID   PLAYERNAME   CHARNAME   NICKNAME   RACE
```

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to use that id row to retrieve the strings (which I then change edittext's to, that part I know, but it's getting those strings that I can't suss out)

Ideally I just want to say to the database, give me all the strings from the row with id 1 and the database to say here you are their "david" "zarr" "the great" "choatic" "human"

ok the answer came from Pitty

A change of the database geto one method to :

```
    public Cursor getOneData(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+table_name+" WHERE ID='" + id + "'",null);
    return res;
}
```

and a change of the method i was using to call it :

```
    public void getOneId(int id){
    Cursor res = characterDB.getOneData(id);
    if(res.getCount() == 0){showmessage("Error","no Data");
        return;}
    else{


        if (res != null && res.moveToFirst()); do {
        showmessage("test","retreived id "+res.getString(0)+" which is "+res.getString(1));
        displaySheet(res.getString(0),
                res.getString(1),
                res.getString(2),
                res.getString(3),
                res.getString(4),
                res.getString(5),
        ); } while (res.moveToNext()); }
```

}

Comment: Check your log, I'm sure there is an error in there. Your query is wrong. If you want to select a specific row, you should have something like `"SELECT * FROM " + table_name + " WHERE id='" + id + "'"`. Also, please read about [Prepared Statements](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: i don't understand what are trying to achieve but you are passing int id as in select projection statment. if you want to find out all records of particular id then add where condition of it means select * from tableName where id=? . right now according to my understanding you are adding id in select projection section .

Comment: i had a filter set to show only errors, set it to verbose and there was the error.. 
"android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1" 
that makes no sense as im requesting id 1 (im calling the function with     getOneId(1);
i have changed the line in the database helper to :
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+table_name+ " WHERE ID='" + id + "'",null); 
but same error (captilised ID as that is how the row is labled, but tried lowercase to) i am really stuped, attmpting to read through the link (its 4am here, been stuck on this for a few hours)

Comment: mcd, the first columm is an integral value that increments with each new database row,its my key row, so each row contains 80 seperate strings and that one id, im trying to get at those strings by using the id row, wierd thing is my show all data method works flawlessly, so why is my get one id row not

Comment: ok please ask proper question . sorry i am little bit harsh but it will confusing to understand  your problem. you have id collumn which are autoincrement with other collumns as you suggest as String right. so now you want row with particuslar id . right if yes then you are passing autoincrement id in wrong section .pass it as where condition . i thing your table structure are shown below according to my understaing

id string1 string2 string3
1    abc    def       ghi
and another point you get cursor index out of bound exception because you tell sqlite to fetch only one result.

Comment: and you are query more then one result .

Comment: yep sorry been stuck on it a few hours before i posted and sleep deprevation is not making me very good at explaining things, have edited the original post to show the table structure and end goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching Id column in your query and you want entire one row for that Use this :

```
public Cursor getOneData(int id){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+table_name+" WHERE id='" + id + "'",null);
if (res != null && res.moveToFirst()) { 
do { 
    //Call Your Function
   } 
while (res.moveToNext()); 
}
 return res;
 }
```

Comment: im getting "android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1"

Comment: if (res != null && res.moveToFirst());
    do {
       ....
    } while (res.moveToNext());
}

Comment: that worked great, i dont understand why it worked though (will read through it all again after i have had some sleep as im pretty fried at the minute, though will update the original post with the solution before i sleep (if you update your answer with that bit too i can mark it as the correct one)

Comment: Yes Sure Happy to Help you